# Possible causes of mongodb findAll() method to load slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, spring-mongodb

I have around 50k data in mongodb collection. I am Pulling all data from using findAll() using spring framework. It takes around 30 seconds to load all the data in a arraylist.

```
What could be various reasons for data to take this long time to load where there is no indexing required.
```

There is no latency. The application and db server are in same server and RAM is sufficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you querying against fields that are not indexed?

Comment: I am trying to get all data from the collection.